# Missing localization for LinkManager in Sitecore

Tags: localization, sitecore, rad-controls

I have a problem with the localization of the LinkManager which is a part of the Sitecore Rich Text Editor.

The LinkManager in Sitecore which can be accessed through the rich text editor does not show any labels anymore.

We upgraded from 6.3 to 6.6. Before the upgrade it had worked fine. The language we are using in the backend is german.

The folder sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Localization\ exists and there are german localization files as well.

Does someone has an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try making a change to the standard Sitecore LinkProvider settings in web.config to this - languageEmbedding="always" and languageLocation="filePath". Restart the Sitecore client and see if that has helped.

Comment: I think the issue is with the actual dialogs in the shell itself, not front-facing URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay folks. Got it!

I had to rename the german language files in sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Localization\

from RadEditor.*.**de**.resx to RadEditor.*.**de-DE**.resx

Now localization is working fine!